# Where can i found advanced courses about blockchain security?

Tags: blockchain, security, defi

Where can i found advanced courses and walkthrough box like TryHackMe and HackTheBox, about blockchain security and Defi, ethical hacking with challenges todo to learn about it.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For smart contract security, you can check [Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/) by OpenZeppelin and [Capture The Ether](https://capturetheether.com/). But if you are asking a general box, as far as I know there is still no something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems interesting, i will start with that.

Comment: If it will helps you, can you mark my answer as solution?

Comment: Good answer Fatih. An experienced user on these forums also taught me that we should also try to answer such questions generally, by explaining what terms to search for.
In this example, it looks like searching for "ethereum ctf" (no quotes) lists a lot of good references. This also helps reduce answers from promoting specific resources directly.

Comment: Good to know that. After that I will try to answer as you said. Thank you very much!